# Convert strings in numpy ndarray to nan (or even better replace by interpolated values)

Tags: python, pandas, excel, string, numpy

I have an excel sheet that contains a matrix. Unfortunately, it happens that some random cells are arbitrary strings. The first row and column are the axes (independent variables). An example:

|  | 10 | 20 | ... | 90 | 100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 9 | ... | blob | 27 |
| 3 | -1 | 10 | ... | blib | 12 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 15 | 0 | blub | ... | bleb | 17 |

I read this in with `pandas` and convert it to `numpy ndarray` in order to work with it.

```
tmp = pd.read_excel('path')
y = tmp.iloc[1:,0].values
x = tmp.iloc[0,1:].values
mat = tmp.iloc[1:,1:].values
```

My first hope was that `numpy`converts the strings automatically to some numerical representation. But I needed to learn that a `ndarray` can hold mixed types.

Sorry, I am not even able to present a minimal example of how `mat` looks like.

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.ndarray(((3,9,'blob',27),(-1,10,'blib',12),(0,'blub','bleb',17))) # raises an error
mat = np.asarray(((3,9,'blob',27),(-1,10,'blib',12),(0,'blub','bleb',17))) # fills the ndarray with strings only (even the numbers become '3', '9' etc.)
```

The above excel import yields numbers in some cells but strings in others.

Is there any efficient way to replace all those strings in `mat` by `np.nan`? I mean, without scanning through all cells and replace based on the type? I tried to do this by the `dtype` argument of `pd.read_excel()` but without much success.

What I finally want to achieve is to replace those original strings by linear interpolated values. So maybe there is even a more efficient way to directly interpolate instead of first numerize the strings. As you see, the strings can also sit in a complete column, so 2D interpolation is required.

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'`.

Comment: pandas columns with strings will be `object` dtype, and any `values` array will also be object.  `numpy` has a `astype(float)` method, but if any string does not represent a valid number if will give an error.  String 'nan' will convert to `np.nan`, a float.  It may be easier to make string substituions in pandas first,

Comment: These brought me much nearer, thanks. Unfortunately, both require scanning through every DataFrame column because ```to_numeric()``` as well as ```replace()``` only work on Series. But better than scanning through every cell! Though both work, I go for ```to_numeric()```, which seems more elegant and shorter to me.
I resist for the moment to post a solution because I still hope to find a good way to replace strings by interpolated values directly instead of firstly set NaN to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) on a whole dataframe in combination with [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) expression to get rid of strings, and then use Pandas [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) to fill in the missing values.

Here is a naive example based on your post, where you seem to deal only with signed integers and simple strings (otherwise, a different regex pattern might be necessary).

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, "a", 2], "col2": [-9, 7, "b"]})

print(df)
# Output  col1 col2
0    1   -9
1    a    7
2    2    b
```

```py
df = df.replace(regex=r"\w+", value=np.nan).interpolate(method="linear")

print(df)
# Output

   col1  col2
0   1.0  -9.0
1   1.5   7.0
2   2.0   7.0
```

Comment: This is not yet the solution because I have a column that completely contains strings. This column remains NaN then. However, this answer adds a lot to it, thank you! I changed your suggestions as follows to also get rid of the NaN column:
```df.replace(regex=r"\w+", value=np.nan).interpolate(method="linear", axis=1).interpolate(method="linear")```